# Is there a way to set underline to mnemonic character in native look and feel under Win 7?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, key-events, mnemonics

My code:

```
fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
fileMenu.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
```

[Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setDisplayedMnemonicIndex%28int%29) for `AbstractButton.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex()` say that

> Not all look and feels may support this.

I set my look and feel to `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`

And I don't see underline on mnemonic even when the index is explicitely  set by `setDisplayedMnemonicIndex()` - under Windows 7 (only when I press `ALT`).

It works however if I do not set the look & feel and leave just default java theme.

Is there a way to achieve this? Is it caused by the settings of Windows ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the behaviour that the underline only appears when pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key by setting a property with the `UIManager`

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Button.showMnemonics", Boolean.TRUE);
```

I think you need to do this before you display your first Swing component, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

An underline will appear when you press the `ALT` key. I think it's intended as a visual feedback for user, to let them know that the underlined characters are now mapped to the corresponding keys as shortcuts.

Comment: I would have posted this as comment, if I had the privilege.

Comment: @Anas I know it it displayed after I press `ALT`. Is this how all windows applications work? +1 so you can get privilege faster:)

Comment: @horse - YEAH exactly. It worked. That is the correct answer. Too bad I cannot mark it and set this question as solved.